# Как вычислить ширину гиперссылки в пикселях?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть код гиперссылки:

```html
<li class="submenu__title">
                  <a href="#">Крупная бытовая техника</a>
</li>
```

Как вычислить ее длину (точную ее ширину в `px` в отображаемой HTML странице - длину текста Крупная бытовая техника в `px`) в ***html*** и ***css***?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните ваш вопрос. Вам нужно вычислить количество символов в тексте ссылки, URL или HTML-коде?

Comment: @Ortophius не количество символов, а ширину в px.

Comment: @Ortophius я прояснил?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let width = document.querySelector('.link');
console.log('Ширина:',width.offsetWidth,'px');
```

```css
a {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a>
```

> длину текста Крупная бытовая техника в px

```js
let width = document.querySelector('.submenu__title>a');
console.log('Ширина:',width.offsetWidth,'px');
```

```html
<li class="submenu__title">
  <a href="#">Крупная бытовая техника</a>
</li>
```

**upd.**

> а как обратиться свойству offsetWidth из html кода, а не из js? – newmandvin

кликнуть по ссылке, чтобы узнать ширину

```html
<li class="submenu__title">
  <a href="#" onclick="alert(offsetWidth)">Крупная бытовая техника</a>
</li>
```

Comment: а как обратиться свойству offsetWidth из html кода, а не из js?

Comment: я имел ввиду, что марджины иконки высчитываются исходя из значения clientWidth надписи (иконка располагается сбоку (а надпись по центру) и марджины для нее высчитываются исходя из клиентвидфа для надписи). Каким образом это можно осуществить? (alert - это все еше js код, а не html)

Comment: нужен второй upd (повторяю alert - это js код, а необходимо получить значение свойства offset выше процедуры onclick, на уровне html-кода) и также обратиться к этому свойству в css коде?

Comment: вы меня поняли или надо прояснить?

Comment: _"длину текста Крупная бытовая техника в px"_ - это не длина текста. Если внутри будет перенос, то они будут отличаться.

Comment: @goodsoft, вот и спрашивал бы в вопросе, как сверстать иконки, а не то, что ты спросил.