# Использование flex для выравнивания внутри пункта меню li

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Привожу текущее состояние кода

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .menu {
      position: relative;
      width: 370px;
    }
    
    .menu ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .menu li {
      padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0em;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    ul.level1 {
      border: 1px solid thistle;
    }
    
    ul.level1>li {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid thistle;
    }
    
    ul.level1>li>a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      line-height: 32px;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    }
    
    .one::before,
    .two::before {
      content: "";
      float: left;
      display: block;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-right: 16px;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      background-size: 25px;
    }
    
    .one::before {
      background-image: url(http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/1/615/w255h2421390849748Sushi09.png);
    }
    
    .two::before {
      background-image: url(http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/1/615/w255h2421390849748Sushi19.png);
    }
    
    ul.level1>li:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    
    ul.level2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: -25px;
      left: 100%;
      max-width: 559px;
      max-height: 1010px;
      padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid thistle;
      visibility: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      column-count: 2;
    }
    
    ul.level2>li {
      padding: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    
    ul.level2>ul>li {
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    ul.level2>li>ul>li {
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    ul.level1>li:hover ul.level2 {
      visibility: visible;
    }
    
    .menu a {
      color: #333;
    }
    
    .alignblock {
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .submenu__title {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .submenu__title a {
      display: block;
      color: black;
      font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
      /* line-height: 1.5; */
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
    }
    
    .submenu__item {
      /* margin-bottom: 0px; */
    }
    
    .submenu__item a {
      display: block;
      color: gray;
      font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 7px;
    }
    
    body {
      display: block;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mainwrap">
    <div class="mainmenu">
      <span>
                <span>
                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#menu" class="hamburger animated fadeInLeft noclose is-open" type="button">
                    <span class="hamb-top"></span>
      <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
      <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
      <span><div class="label menu-label" id="myelement">КАТАЛОГ ТОВАРОВ</div></span>
      </span>

      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="level1">
          <li id="l1">
            <div class="alignblock">Бытовая техника для кухни</div>
            <ul class="level2">
              <li class="submenu">
                <ul>
                  <li class="submenu__title">
                    <a href="#">Крупная бытовая техника</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                  <li class="submenu__title">
                    <a href="#">New title</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="l2">
            <div class="alignblock">Item 2</div>
          </li>
          <li id="l3">
            <div class="alignblock">Item 3 +</div>
            <ul class="level2">
              <li>Sub-Item 3-1</li>
              <li>Sub-Item 3-2</li>
              <li>Sub-Item 3-3</li>
              <li>Sub-Item 3-4</li>
              <li>Sub-Item 3-5</li>
              <li>Sub-Item 3-6</li>
              <li>Sub-Item 3-7</li>
              <li>Sub-Item 4-8</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="l2">
            <div class="alignblock">Item 4</div>
          </li>
          <li id="l2">
            <div class="alignblock">Item 5</div>
          </li>
          <li id="l2">
            <div class="alignblock">Item 6</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Каким образом можно с помощью `flex` запихнуть иконку сбоку , а текст расположить по центру пункта меню `li`? Должно быть как на рисунке (сайт http://positronica.ru)

[image: Цель редактирования]

Иконки для редактирования

[image: Пробная иконка]

Comment: @Barmaley (если вы меня помните - то я с hashcode.ru - ivan31). Помогите разобраться с проблемой. Обращаюсь к вам поскольку вы хороший специалист в области ИТ.

Comment: @MaximLensky и вы подтягивайтесь. Бармалей - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley (очень умный человек, еще мне на hashcode.ru отвечал)

Comment: @MaximLensky а с помощью flex-а как сделать?

Comment: @MaximLensky а что если надпись должна быть строго по центру (пустые div-ы вставлять можно к примеру - но это не самый лучший вариант), поэтому про flex-ы и спрашиваю

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/mdOxyBa - вот так в общем - дальше сами

Comment: @MaximLensky  а что делать на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1249311/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%85 (ваше мнение будет не лишнем) насчет html и css